# Is there a better way than writing multiple If statements that almost do same thing

Tags: asp.net, if-statement, c#-4.0

I have multiple **if statements** in one of the function, 22 to be exact. All **if statements** almost do same thing which makes function looks very big.

For e.g

```
    if( filter.FirstIds != null )
    {
        foreach( var activityId in filter.FirstIds )
        {
            var first = DataWarehouseData.DimFirsts.FirstOrDefault( a => a.FirstID == firstId );

            if( first != null )
            {
                firstSKs.Add( first.FirstSK );
            }
        }

        skCollection.Add( "FirstSK", firstSKs );
    }

    if( filter.SecondIds != null )
    {
        foreach( var SecondId in filter.SecondIds )
        {
            var Second = DataWarehouseData.DimSeconds.FirstOrDefault( s => s.SecondID == secondId );

            if( second != null )
            {
                secondSKs.Add( Second.SecondSK );
            }
        }

        skCollection.Add( "SecondSK", SecondSKs );
    }
```

**filter** is a chart filter and I cannot apply a foreach loop on it as it doesn't have GetEnumerator() function.

What actually is happening that I am going through all the 22 DataMembers(Properties) of filter and depending upon the DataMember, extracting the data from specific table. So if I am checking **filter.FirstIds** than data will come from **DimFirsts** table, if **filterData.SecondIds** than data will come from **DimSeconds** table, etc.

I tried to search on google but as it is specific scenario, I am not able to find any way to achieve this. I find out Reflection and tried to use the same here to reduce the code but no success.

Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: Is DWReportData a Entity Framework DBContext? Or just an in-memory structure?

Comment: And how many entries does the ID collection typically contain (order of magnitude)?

Comment: @jeroenh Yes, DWReportData is an Entity Framework DBContext. There could be at max 100 entries for a particular ID collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, I don't know exact types of anything or the overall structure of your code, but the basic idea is as follows:

```
void PerformFiltering<T>(IEnumerable<int> ids, Func<int, T> resolveItemCallback, Action<T> addItemCallback, Action addCollectionCallback)
{
    if(ids == null) return;

    foreach(var id in ids)
    {
        var item = resolveItemCallback(id);
        if(item == null) return;

        addItemCallback(item);
    }

    addCollectionCallback();
}
```

With this function, your code turns into:

```
PerformFiltering<DimActivity>(
    filterData.ActivityIds, 
    id => DWReportData.DimActivities.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ActivityID == id),
    i => activitySKs.Add(i), 
    () => skCollection.Add("ActivitySK", activitySKs));

PerformFiltering<DimSite>(
    filterData.FromSiteIds, 
    id => DWReportData.DimSites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SiteID == id),
    i => srcSiteSKs.Add(i), 
    () => skCollection.Add("SrcSiteSK", srcSiteSKs));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works perfectly after slight modification.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to initialize collection by default, in constructor, for not to have it null. Even if collection is empty - for and foreach loop will not be executed.

If you can not modify object with collection - you could use ?? operator like this:

```
foreach (int activityId in filterData.ActivityIds ?? new List<int>())
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make an boolean array containing the expressions value and then execute in a loop like

```
for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
if(arr[i])
{
//your code that to be repeated
}
}
```